# Do composer commands manually

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I want to connect a payment gateway in my laravel project. I can do that with composer but This script is located on the host and I do not have access to SSH.
Do you know how can I do these two commands manually?

```
      composer require econea/nusoap:dev-master



      php artisan make:controller siteController
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the package to the **vendor** folder

Add a reference in *`\vendor\composer\autoload_namespaces.php`*

Add a reference in *`\vendor\composer\autoload_psr4.php`*

Work automatically now when the *`vendor\autoload.php`* is called

---

```
php artisan make:controller siteController
```

This will create a controller, The created can be seen at *`app/Http/Controllers`*.

Used for a  create a new controller without a composer:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class siteController extends Controller
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Tnx this is for the package, how can I create a new controller without composer?